# Шарик скатывающийся по наклонной плоскости

Tags: c++, opengl, физика

Пишу проект в OpenGL на C++.

Дана наклонная плоскость, по которой скатывается и затем останавливается шарик. Шарик есть, плоскость есть (нарисовать их не проблема). Дело осталось за малым, чтобы шарик скатывался и останавливался... но вот как это сделать? (я знаю, что должна еще применяться формула притяжения)

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: пы сы, помоему не вяжетсо немного название со здравым смыслом, си в opengl? может таки наоборот? OpenGL в Си

Comment: А вообще, OpenGL тут не при чём. Физика везде одинаковая.

Comment: Поддержу))

Answer (score 1):

Да не надо там формулы притяжения, просто наращивайте скорость, что-то типа
speed += 5;
positionX = x + speed;
positionY = y + speed;

Я на с++ не пишу уже давно но думаю суть ясна...
Если задача чтобы скотился шарик - нет смысла заморачиватся над законом тяготения...
Мог бы еще и про наклоны посоветовать, но вы ненаписали какие у вас углы...
В любом случае удачи...

PS: *Настя.Магадан* эта к чему? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Во время скатывания шарика:

```
speed.x+=g*cos(a);
speed.y-=g*sin(a);
pos.x+=speed.x;
pos.y+=speed.y;
```

g - это ускорение свободного падения, зависит от масштаба и скорости скатывания.
 a - угол наклона плоскости в радианах.
 Возможнно cos и sin нужно поменять местами.

Чтобы шарик останавливался, нужно вычитать из его скорости силу трения.

Comment: какой смысл считать скорость незная массы?<br>
Ваша формула бессмыслена, для вычесления реального ускорения обязательно необходимо знать массу, т.к. она неизвестна - ИМХО лучший вариант скорость просто прикинуть, записать ее в константу и просто добавлять ее к уже существующей скорости...<br>
Про силу трения так-же неясно...<br>
Если предположить что плоскость наклонена то шарик кагбы будет катится без остановки, не?

Comment: Насколько я помню из курса физики, ускорение при падении не зависит от массы. От массы зависит сила притяжения. А ускорение для всех тел одинаковое.

Трение можно пренебречь. Мы же не реальные физические процессы моделируем. К тому же, трение качения не велико.

Comment: Именно одинаково, и из ваты, и из металла. Другое дело - сопротивление воздуха. Шарик из ваты из-за рыхлой структуры испытывает бОльшее сопротивление. В вакууме они будут падать одинаково. Опыты Галилея, 16 век.  А качение под силой тяжести то же, что и свободное падение. Голубчик, у Вас что по физике было?

Comment: А ТС писала о вакууме? Покажите мне хоть 1о упоминание о вакууме в вопросе ТСа и потом поговорим...

Comment: Хорошо, вводи аэродинамические уравнения, учитывай турбулентность, случайные порывы ветра, трение поверхности,то, что Аннушка пролила масло, и т.д. Счастливого пути. Может, к Рождеству и посчитай что-нибудь.

Если не указано иного, моделируем по самому простому варианту. Искусство моделирования - искусство упрощения.

Comment: вставлю 5 копеек про вакум, тс не писал и обратного, и в самом деле масса обьекта не имеет значения,тс узнавал только про формулу ускорения под действием силы притяжения, там нет ни слова что нужно применять формулы трения, учитывать аэродинамичесские характеристики...

Comment: Я опечален... А я писал о трении? Я вообще писал что не вижу смысла что-то считать т.к. масса заранее неизвестна... 
<br>@mikillskegg к чему крайности то такие?<br>

Comment: В вопросе говорилось, что шарик должен останавливаться. Если силы трения не будет, то от чего же шарик тогда остановится?

Comment: @AlexWindHope Странно, что вы не видите смысла что-либо считать без знания массы. **Есть задача, ее можно решить - так почему бы не сделать этого?**.

*Масса шарика здесь влияет только на время, которое пройдет до окончания его движения, т.к от этой самой массы зависит сила трения.*

Comment: @AlexWindHope И если не ударяться в крайности *(например, изучать движение шариков массой `1 грамм` или `20 тонн`)*, то эта сила трения **легко может аппроксимироваться некоторой константой.**

Что мы имеем в итоге - моделируемый процесс независит от массы шарика и выглядит правдодобно. Тем более, что, учитывая "жизненные" коэффициенты силы трения трения, шарики массой `5 килограмм` и `6 килограмм` уедут на расстояния, отличающиеся очень незначительно.

Comment: Если плоскость наклонена то шарик будет катится все время...<br>
Посему я не понимаю о чем вы вообще?<br>
Если надо чтобы он останавливался то это же не имеет никакого отношения к реальной физике... Вы помоему пытаетесь все мне что-то доказать а не решить поставленную задачу...

Comment: @AlexWindHope Как я понял условие - есть наклонная плоскость, с которой шарик разгоняется и переходит на плоскость с нулевым углом наклона. **Надо уточнить у автора вопроса.**

Comment: Да об стенку шарик останавливается!

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, о чем базар. Задача максимально проста. Если не указаны иные условия, то движение происходит в вакууме, ускорение движения постоянное, трение о поверхность отсутствует, поверхность идеально гладкая, шарик идеально круглый и т.д. И не надо городить огород на пустом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Писал 3хмерки на делфе, если вам физ модель нужна то советую смотреть в сторону уроков Nehe там есть и коллизи(чтоб не проваливался сквозь обьекты), и гравитация и много примеров именно по OpenGL + С++ + физика....